# Why MongoDB C++ Driver not working on SLES11?

Tags: c++, linux, mongodb, boost, sles

I've been working on installing the MongoDB drivers on Zlinux, and so far, I've got it all to work on most Linux systems apart from SLES11.

Now in order to get the code on, I had to do a number of updates to the GCC and Boost. This means the system is running the following:

```
test@ff6d8405cc0c:~/work> g++ --version
g++ (GCC) 5.2.0
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

test@ff6d8405cc0c:~/work> cat /usr/local/include/boost/version.hpp | grep "BOOST_LIB_VERSION"
//  BOOST_LIB_VERSION must be defined to be the same as BOOST_VERSION
#define BOOST_LIB_VERSION "1_58"
test@ff6d8405cc0c:~/work> cat /usr/include/boost/version.hpp | grep "BOOST_LIB_VERSION"
//  BOOST_LIB_VERSION must be defined to be the same as BOOST_VERSION
#define BOOST_LIB_VERSION "1_36"
```

So as I have 2 version of boost I've set my path as follows:

```
test@ff6d8405cc0c:~/work> echo $PATH
/home/test/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin:/usr/games:/usr/lib/mit/bin:/usr/lib/mit/sbin:.:/usr/local/include/:/usr/local/lib/
```

But my g++ script to test connection to the DB is still failing, this is the script:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include "mongo/client/dbclient.h" // for the driver

void run() {
 mongo::DBClientConnection c;
  c.connect("localhost");
}

int main() {
    mongo::client::initialize();
    try {
        run();
        std::cout << "connected ok" << std::endl;
   } catch( const mongo::DBException &e ) {
        std::cout << "caught " << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

My install of the MongoDB C++ driver works as expected using the following scons flags:

```
sudo scons --prefix=/usr/local --disable-warnings-as-errors install
```

**But part of me suspects from the error that it's calling the wrong libraries for boost. As when I try to compile the C++, I just get a load of errors:**

> test@ff6d8405cc0c:~/work> g++ example-connect.cpp -pthread -lmongoclient -lboost_thread -lboost_system -lboost_program_options -lboost_system -lboost_regex -o example-connect
>       /usr/local/lib/gcc/s390x-ibm-linux-gnu/5.2.0/../../../libmongoclient.a(dbclient.o): In function `boost::thread_exception::thread_exception(int, char const*)':
>       /usr/local/include/boost/thread/exceptions.hpp:51: undefined reference to`boost::system::system_category()'
>       /usr/local/lib/gcc/s390x-ibm-linux-gnu/5.2.0/../../../libmongoclient.a(dbclient.o): In function `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0':
>       /usr/local/include/boost/system/error_code.hpp:221: undefined reference to`boost::system::generic_category()'
>       /usr/local/include/boost/system/error_code.hpp:222: undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()'
>       /usr/local/include/boost/system/error_code.hpp:223: undefined reference to`boost::system::system_category()'
>       /usr/local/lib/gcc/s390x-ibm-linux-gnu/5.2.0/../../../libmongoclient.a(dbclient.o): In function `boost::re_detail::perl_matcher<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator, std::allocator > >, std::allocator, std::allocator > > > >, boost::regex_traits > >::match_prefix()':

I've done a bit of research myself, but I'm not 100% sure what to do next to be sure that I'm calling all the right components.

Comment: The build doesn't search /usr/local by default, and I don't see that you have used the --extrapath or --cppath and --libpath flags to specify it. Please read https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-cxx-driver/wiki/Download-and-Compile-The-Legacy-Driver, in particular, see https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-cxx-driver/wiki/Download-and-Compile-the-Legacy-Driver#path-options. Also, be aware that building against non-system boost can be tricky, especially w.r.t. ensuring that the interposed boost completely masks the system version, and dealing with runtime paths if you link dynamically.

Comment: Thanks very much, I will take a look at these things now that I'm back from holiday and report back as to how it went.